# Why does Colab extract a Google Drive .tar file to /content directory (and not to Google Drive)?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I use Colab. I am amazed by the following behavior:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks")
```

or

```
!ls -al /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks
```

returns: ['FGNET_all.tar']

When I extract FGNET_all.tar

```
!tar xvf /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/FGNET_all.tar
```

FGNET is extracted to /content directory:

```
os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks")
```

=> Only ['FGNET_all.tar']  not FGNET directory

```
os.listdir("/content")
```

or

```
!ls -al /content
```

returns
['.config', 'drive', '._FGNET', 'FGNET'] => FGNET directory

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the destination is specified, `tar` command extracts contents of the file to the working directory. Default working directory of Google Colab is the `/content` folder, which is why your extracted file is saved there.

You can specify the destination directory as follows:

```
!tar xvf /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/FGNET_all.tar -C /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/
```